# Easymock call autowired object method

Tags: java, spring, testing, easymock

Let's say I have Following classes:

```
public class A {
@Autowired B b;
public void doSomething(){
   b.doSomeThingElse();
}


@Component
@Autowired C c;
public class B {
public void doSomethingElse(){
  c.doIt();
}
```

How can I test A when you know I want to mock `c.doIt()` but want to call `b.doSomethingElse();` with EasyMock?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Autowired` is nice but tend to make us forget about how to test. Just add a setter for `b` and `c`.

```
C c = mock(C.class);
c.doIt();

replay(c);

B b = new B();
b.setC(c);
A a = new A();
a.setB(b);

a.doSomething();

verify(c);
```

Or use constructor injection.

```
C c = mock(C.class);
c.doIt();

replay(c);

B b = new B(c);
A a = new A(b);

a.doSomething();

verify(c);
```

In this case, your classes become:

```
public class A {
    private B b;
    public A(B b) { // Spring will autowired by magic when calling the constructor
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void doSomething() {
        b.doSomeThingElse();
    }
}

@Component
public class B {
    private C c;
    public B(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public void doSomethingElse(){
        c.doIt();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. but I used: ReflectionTestUtils.setField, But you're answer would work as well

Comment: It works as well. I could have answer that but I don't really like it. Breaks encapsulation when it's not necessary